# Sort data collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have a collection_check_boxes with custom data. In my model I have a method like this:

```
def label
   [social_profile.name, I18n.t(source_type_code, scope: 'enum.source_type.name')].join(' - ')
end
```

And in my view I have this:

```
= f.collection_check_boxes(:source_ids, @sources, :id, :label)
```

But I need to sort the data returned by my method label alphabetically. How can I do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it when you are saving data in @sources

It seems like you are getting data from database, you need to do it in query

```
Source.all.order(name: :desc)
```